# Not able to edit the favorite tags, when the user is already viewing the questions tagged to a particular favorite tag

Tags: bug, tag-watching

From home page, choose a favorite tag. the list of questions tagged to it will be displayed-> try editing the favorite tags, script error is thrown.
User has to go to the home page to edit the tags again.

Comment: Can you provide more information, like what error you get, which browser and version you're using, etc? I just tried this and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Message: Script error Line: 0 Char: 0 Code: 0 URI: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js?v=17f3c18c5086 I am usig IE 8 browser

Comment: Script error on Line 0, Char 0 sounds like a corrupted download.. What browser do you use, what platform, did you try to clear your browser cache?

Comment: [IE8 is not an offically supported browser.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need) All sorts of things can and will break in it. Try one that is.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in a browser that is no longer officially supported.